# Sitecore User Group Poland (SUGPL) - 01 December 2017

Tags: discussion, status-completed

- Date/Time (local): Friday, 1 December 2017 at 5:00pm
- Date/Time (UTC): Friday, 1 December 2017 at 4:00pm
- Location: Wadowicka 6D, Cracow, Poland
- Event details: [meetup details and registration](https://sugplmeetup.evenea.pl/)
- Contact: [sugpl.info](http://sugpl.info/en/contact/)
- Streaming: yes, link will be published on Sitecore Slack 1 hour before the even
- Sponsors: Sabre, Sii, intive, SoftServe, Brimit, Sitecore
- Presentations:

  - "Sitecore 9 xConnect how tos, xConnect and Marketing Automation" by Daniil Raschupkin and Alexei Vershalovich
  - "100% Availability - Scale your System landscape and processes waterproof" by Sebastian Winter
  - "Sitecore 9 - what's new for Developers, DevOps and Content Authors" by Tomasz Juranek

Comment: Event promotion has started

Comment: Videos are now available on [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKpgjVmaG2CEpCAK4xQkAWQ/videos)   
, photos are available here [Google Gallery](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOIc_BaoPLs8fxNqFwmCKPP-VCBw0ViGoOE45xrPgTN13Hl4kxOz4Hzbqg_joCWAQ?key=bnFKTjdUdTVKdjBJMXdpMEJ3VUltT1diNEQ0RnFB)